# remove item in ng-repeat using particular id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backend

assume I already got my id, is this the correct way of removing an item of a list? I don't think so because it doesn't work. I tried:

```
$scope.postItem.splice(id, 1);
```

my partial html and js here http://jsfiddle.net/Jk7RB/

I don't understand the $index method, so I get the post_id instead. It's easier because I can straight away remove the item by the id in backend.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jquery**

use [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method like this:

```
$('#your_id').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have id of li:

**Using Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("li_id").remove();
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
$('#li_id').remove();
```